# Button action with @UiHandler not being hit

Tags: java, button, gwt, uibinder

I am currently having issues implementing a button event with the `@UiHandler` annotation. In my .xml file I have my button defined as `ui:field="clearAllButton"`.
In the class (`ServerTaskSchedulingViewImpl.java`) which I am trying to set up the action I have the following:

```
interface ServerTaskSchedulingViewImplUiBinder
        extends UiBinder<Widget, ServerTaskSchedulingViewImpl> {}

private static final ServerTaskSchedulingViewImplUiBinder uiBinder =
        GWT.create(ServerTaskSchedulingViewImplUiBinder.class);

....
....
@UiField
Button clearAllButton;
....
....
@UiHandler("clearAllButton")
void clearAllButtonClicked(ClickEvent clickEvent) {
    System.out.println("Button action performed");
}
```

When I set a break point in the `clearAllButtonClicked` function, it is never hit.

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Which version are you using? SuperDevMode or classic DevMode? Breakpoint set in the browser dev tools or your IDE? Which IDE?

Comment: IntelliJ 14 ultimate. I don't have trouble getting breakpoints to be hit normally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue- my .xml file was not named the same as my .java class file although the xml UiField and java variable names did match. Changing the name of the .xml file to JobViewImpl.ui.xml and class name to JobViewImpl.java. This resolved the issue

Answer (score 1):

Looks correct but a breakpoint here will never be hit because it's all javascript that's running. Try using SuperDevMode and set a breakpoint in the browser instead.

Comment: @Baz OP did not specify any of that.

Comment: True, but claiming the breakpoints will never be hit without knowing how the code is run isn't worth an answer in my opinion.

Comment: @Baz Maybe, which is why I added the comment about it being javascript that is running and not Java. Also, DevMode is kind of deprecated.

Comment: OP states in his comment that _"I don't have trouble getting breakpoints to be hit normally"_, which indicades he is using DevMode (or SuperDevMode) already. And yes, it may be deprecated, but it's way more useful than debugging in the browser. Anyway, let's end this discussion as it's going nowhere.